# Dependencies between projects with Haskell Stack build tool -- best workflow?

Tags: haskell, package-managers, project-structure, build-system, haskell-stack

I am just beginning a relatively large Haskell project using the `stack` package manager and build tool, and I am trying to figure out the best way to split it up into several `stack` projects with dependencies between them.

Essentially, while I believe I understand how to use `stack` to include external packages downloaded from Stackage in my project, I don't understand how to include packages from other local projects.  How do I create libraries using `stack` that I can then use in other projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `stack.yaml` there is the field `packages`. This is where you can specify the locations of other projects.

For an example, see the stack.yaml file for the hayoo repo:

https://github.com/hunt-framework/hayoo/blob/master/stack.yaml